# TypeError: Invalid Version: Not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

after upgrading all of my packages, once I run `gulp`, this is what I am getting

```
TypeError: Invalid Version: Not installed
Invalid Version: Not installed (CLI v1.6.1)
'run-ionic' errored after 12 s
[10:12:30] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command `ionic serve` failed with exit code 1
```

and:

```
Invalid Version: Not installed (CLI v1.6.1)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0-nightly-1299
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
Node Version: v0.12.4
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was trying to start a new ionic app and got the same error. I guess you already have npm installed, but the Cordova CLI is not installed so I suggest you to install in the terminal by npm.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

It worked for me, I hope it helps you.